# design two sets of layouts for a project

Tags: android, layout

the look and feel of my project should be different for men and women. it means all backgrounds and text fonts for men layouts should be different from those for women. I want to know is it possible to define two sets of layout(like extra layout folder) or I should put IF before setContentView(layout) in every activity and fragment.

Comment: Do you need to change only the text Style and the background of the view,or you want to change the layout as a whole

Comment: The structure of my layouts are the same but for example image of imageviews or backgrounds can differ.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will suggest you to change the imageview, background and textFont dynamically in java code. If in case you are not comfortable with this, then it will be better to create seperate layout and intent as per the gender goes